# Подстройка ColorBox под размеры экрана

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть ли у плагина *ColorBox* возможность подстраивать свои максимальные размеры под размер экрана?

Имеется компонент, использующий этот плагин, поэтому если то, что он не подстраивается - это его нормальное поведение - то есть ли какие-нибудь события его разворачивания, чтобы можно было самому установить эти размеры?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Да, есть такой метод 
`$.colorbox.resize().`
Пример: http://jsfiddle.net/9p4y832o/